# How to deal with extra spacing with line-height when spacing between elements should be consistent

Tags: html, grid, css, alignment, white-space

We want to design our website so that all elements are spaced 24px apart (paragraphs, form groups, header & content, etc.) and "related" elements (label & form field) are spaced 8px apart. We are doing this with [flex gap](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox-gap) which works well (we built a polyfill for browsers that don't support this).

This works great for non-text elements. But for paragraphs and headers, a `line-height` > 1 results in additional spacing between the element before and the visual start of the text. The images below are a `div`, `p`, and `div` w/ `row-gap:24px`.

[image: demonstration of line-height 1] [image: demonstration of line-height 1.5] [image: demonstration of line-height 2]

Having this increased space between elements goes against the style (my boss is a real stickler on consistent spacing and will often open up Photoshop to count the pixels). To avoid this problem, we add psudo-elements to every text element with negative margins to compensate for the top and bottom white space. (If CSS supported a `leading` property, this would be easier as it would change the actual spacing between lines of text vs increasing the height of each line.)

[image] [image]

Looking at other sites, I often see a mess of margins and paddings of all different values. Nothing which makes a whole lot of logical sense. Do these developers just keep messing with the numbers until it looks good vs having some standard components to work with?

Perhaps our design/strategy is flawed in some fashion? Is it good that a increased font-size (and line-height increasing as well) would warrant more spacing between elements?

How do you guys deal with the extra spacing caused by `line-height` > 1?

Answer (score -1):

I think it's all about well designed, curated and developed **design system**.

line-height is correlated with typography.

[Example this dribbble picture](https://dribbble.com/shots/4795090-Grid-Section-of-LS-design-system).

---

In .**scss preprocessors** it's possible to define variables

(developers, usually do more intelligent/complex issues than styling 
so this may be the mess you mentioned)

It's possible to define **line-height** on a variable basis and then reuse it
let me explain this in the example above (on eye - not math precision)

- l-h - 1
- l-h - 2
- l-h - 3
- l-h - 4

---

```
$line-height-1: 7.5 
$line-height-2: 4.0
$line-height-3: 1.75 
$line-height-4: 0.625
```

then you can define these values ​​in specific **headers/paragraphs**.

```
p{
 line-height: $line-height-1;
}
```

Comment: Your Dribble link is talking about [rhythm](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-rhythm-1/). Not sure how this is related to the second half of your answer.

Comment: No, it's just an example of well designed line-heights.The point is about the variable system.

Answer (score -3):

You are on the right path .

Seems like you are more experienced than your designer .
**Aesthetics** are important, but designing is much more than just a **pixel perfect** layout. You have to consider about **code quality** also.

The only thing you can do from your side if the designer is not going to rework is trying to manage the code.

List all combinations of possible variations of **font size** and **line-height** used across the system. (again this is also part of **style guides** **typography** section, hope designer have sorted it for you)

Keep those minimal or it is going to be a real mess.

Then define the different classes with a negative margin which is a **flexible** approach (**OOCSS**) or set that margins inside already defined classes (**BEM**).

Again if you have used multiple fonts in the system because not every font has the same **ascender height** you have more work to do, Oops...

What your designer trying to implement is **vertical rhythm** by means of using an 8pt g**rid system** and unfortunately, he/she is not successful or he/she might know it but not implemented in the right way because of your stickler Boss .

I often do bad design and development not because I don't know how to do it but there are circumstances that force me to do so .

Comment: Your feedback is appreciated if one who doesn't find an answer is appropriate. We may improve it.